# Convert one string password to all asterisks

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to encrypt the password when it shows out in registration report, instead of showing the real password I would like to encrypt all the value to an asterisk (*) I tried to replace all character one-by-one to asterisk * but I think that is not the right way to achieve the result.

```
String s1="mypassword";  
String replaceString=s1.replaceAll("a","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("b","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("c","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("d","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("e","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("f","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("g","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("h","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("i","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("j","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("k","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("l","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("m","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("n","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("o","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("p","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("q","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("r","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("s","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("t","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("u","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("v","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("w","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("x","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("y","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("z","*");

replaceString=s1.replaceAll("A","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("B","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("C","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("D","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("E","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("F","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("G","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("H","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("I","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("J","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("K","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("L","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("M","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("N","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("O","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("P","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("Q","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("R","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("S","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("T","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("U","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("V","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("W","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("X","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("Y","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("Z","*");

replaceString=s1.replaceAll("0","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("1","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("2","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("3","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("4","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("5","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("6","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("7","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("8","*");
replaceString=s1.replaceAll("9","*");
System.out.println(replaceString);
```

Comment: You shouldn't have access to the password of a user in clear. It should be encrypted.

Comment: Should the encrypted password be of same length as that of original? It can only 4-5 asterisks representing that password is secret.

Comment: Very strange way. Nut you can write: String asterisk = "*"; asterisk.repeat( mypassword.lenght());

Comment: also, how about `System.out.println("*********");`

Comment: "but I think that is not the right way to achieve the result." indeed, this code would only mask 9s, because the last `replaceAll` is using the original string.

Comment: Do you need to show that there is a password in the report at all?

Comment: Instead of writing a new line of code for *every possible typeable character*, why not just show a string of asterisks the *same length* as the password?  (As an aside, this is **not** "encrypting".)

Comment: Personally I'd just hard-code `"********"` as the "password", because there's no point in even indicating how long the password is. **Really** the plain password should not be stored *at all*, but if you can't change that, then at least don't leak any more information than you absolutely need to.

Comment: As others have said you should not have the password unencrypted anyway.  In addition to that assuming you have a requirement to show there is a password you could just create a new `String` of any length with all "*".  Do NOT use the length of the actual password when display the "*" as this gives away information about the users password.  Again as others has said this is not encryption, not least of which as there is no way back from the "*" form to the original, at best this is "masking".

Answer (score 4):

If `s1` contains *only* the password, you'd want to mask all characters, and you'd end up with a string of the same length, consisting entirely of stars. This can be constructed directly:

```
replaceString = "*".repeat(s1.length());
```

Or, don't show anything about the password at all. Passwords are something that you want to give as little information as possible about, because information can make it (marginally or substantially) easier to guess/crack.

You can show something with a fixed number of stars; but I contend that's not showing anything useful, other than "this user *has* a password", which is presumably the same for all users.

Leave it out, use that space in the report for something else that provides information to the reader.

Comment: You should not use the length of the `s1`.  Apart from giving attackers a clue as to how many characters they need to break, its much easier just to use a fixed string of  of arbitrary length.

Comment: @Gavin well, sure. This is answering OP's question "how do you do this", without addressing the question of "_should you_ do this".

Comment: It is a fine line to tread granted, and I did (briefly) consider a downvote, but as you said you answer the OP's question, and in, to my knowledge ,the best way.  That said, given we are taking about security in this instance I feel educating the OP as to a better solution/best practise might be in all our interests.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to substitute your String with all asterisks, you can try as follow;

```
String s1="mypassword";  
String replaceString="*";
replaceString = replaceString.repeat(s1.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1="mypassword";  
String pass = s1.replaceAll("[\\W\\w]","*")
```

Answer (score 0):

as per the code you can send the static value in the frontend or backend with ******* or in the worst case you can use replaceAll with regular expression to match all different passwords which are possible.

Comment: Up vote for using a static value of arbitrary "*"

Answer (score -1):

Security issues have been brought up already, so I'm just going to focus on the actual "task" here.

There's multiple ways to do this. One of them I would probably choose is this:

Instead of replacing them, as mentioned before, you can just create a new String that is the same length as your password string but fill it only with asterisks. This is pretty much what everybody has suggested already but I'm trying to keep it simple, as it seems like you're more on the beginner-side.

```java
// We start off with an empty new String
String newString = "";
// Then we create a loop that adds a asterisk to the new String exactly, this is called x times where x is the length of the original passwordString
for (int i = 0; i < oldString.length; i++) { // This is a normal for-loop, if you don't know this concept yet, just google 'for-loop java'
    newString = newString + "*"; // Here we set the newString to itself-i.e. the current content of the String plus an asterisk.
}
```

After this loop, we have a new String that has exactly as many characters as the old one but they're all asterisks. Now we could potentially replace the old String with the content of the new one, if that is what you want to do.

```java
oldString = newString;
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right concept I looking for. But this way can only be used when I wan to replace the actual password into asterisk. How about when user entering their password in the login screen, the system will display * when user type their password?

Comment: I think you lack some basic Java knowledge here. You can make the user enter a password and save that to a variable "password". This can then be converted into a new String "asterisks". I suspecting what you mean is an input window that converts the password characters on the fly while typing them in? This is not a typical Java task but can be achieved with a loop much like the one I showed in my reply. (Which btw. I don't know why is being downvoted...)

Comment: @高颜值の美食 all UI frameworks (including HTML forms) provide specialized password input elements, which do this masking (and other things) for you. If you're doing it on the command line, you need to be using something that masks/hides the password correctly, e.g. [`Console.readPassword()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Console.html#readPassword()). If you don't know about these already, I suggest you stop and research best practices around passwords, because this affects the basic security of your system.

Comment: @KonstiLackner my guess as to the down votes are that their methods on `String` which negate the use of the loop.  Checkout Andy Turners answer above

Comment: @Gavin Oh yeah, I was trying to appropriate my answer to the knowledge I thought the person asking the question has

Comment: @KonstiLackner if you think OP lacks knowledge direct him/her to simple, standard API methods, like `repeat`. The problem with encouraging use of things like string concatenation in a loop is that it gives the impression this is a generally-good approach.